# I have a mongo database with the schema:{ "field1":"string1","field2":num2,"field3":num3}

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo database with the schema:

```
{ 

"field1"  :  "string1",
"field2"  :   num2,
"field3"  :   num3

}
```

How do i find all the documents that have the same values for `field2` and `field2` but the value of `field3` is different by 15% ?

my code looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
$group : {
_id  : {"&field1" ,  "$field2"}
  }
})

db.collection.find({$match: "$field3:0})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show what query/queries you've tried, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your desired values for field1 and field2 are "gold" and 1024 respectively, **in relational/sql sudo-language, your query looks something like the following :**

SELECT * FROM collection WHERE field1 = "money" AND field2 = 1024 AND (field3 >= (field2*1.15) OR field3 <= (field2*.85))

**MongoDB sudo-code query :**

```
db.collection.find( {
     field1: "gold",
     field2: 1024,
     $or: [ { field3: { $gt: ("$field2"*1.15) } }, { field3: { $lt: ("$field2"*0.85)} } ]
} )
```

Consider using     db.collection.aggregate ( {...} ) if you want multiple entries

Check out the mongo docs :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: field3 should not be compared with field2.

The field3 of one document should be compared with field3 of the other documents.
I want to find documents which have the same value of field1 and field2  but the value of field3 in one is different than the value of field3 in other by 15%